# How do I show tags related to a specific post in Elementor?

Tags: tags, custom-post-type, elementor

I have created a custom taxonomy of tags using Custom Post Type UI. For each post, I want to show the tags that are related to that specific post, not a list of all the tags. Any suggestions about how to do this? I'm working with Elementor Pro on Wordpress.

I've looked a way to filter the Elementor Tags Cloud widget so that it will only display the tags associated with the post, but haven't found a way to do that.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I tried Post Info block and it didn't work.

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet. Still hoping someone out there can provide some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the code below to create a shortcode in function.php (Appearance -> theme file editor) or it's easier to use the WP Code plugin, the code below will only display tags according to the post.

```
function post_tags_func()
{
  $tags = get_the_tags();
  $return .= '<div class="post-tags">';
  if ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
      $return .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($tag->term_id) . '">#' . $tag->name . '</a>';
    }
  }
  $return .= '</div>';
  return $return;
}

add_shortcode('post_tags', 'post_tags_func');
```

then place the [post_tags] shortcode on the single post template page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Aezo27. The code you provided doesn't pull tags from the custom taxonomy that I have created using ACF. Still, I appreciate your taking the time to share the code.